# JSP Radio Button Values

Tags: forms, jsp, radio-button

I was wondering how to get radio button values. So suppose, I have a form that has two radio buttons. I would like to get the value associated with the button. However, I get null when I try to.

Form portion

```
<form method="post" action="insert.jsp" enctype=text/plain>
<table>
<INPUT TYPE="radio" name="command" value="0">Run<INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="command" VALUE="1">Walk<BR>
```

Insert.jsp portion

```
String sCommand=(String)request.getParameter("command");
out.println(sCommand);
```

So in turn, it prints out null

Comment: did you try checking them before submitting the page? The code looks fine...

Answer (score 4):

Use `GET` method instead of `POST` and your code will run. (if you want to use 'text/plain') and also see the answer given by @divyabharathi for the correct `enctype` for POST method.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="get" action="insert.jsp" enctype=text/plain>
<INPUT TYPE="radio" name="command" value="0"/>Run
<INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="command" VALUE="1"/>Walk
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="submit" />
</form>
<%
String sCommand = request.getParameter("command");
out.println(sCommand);
%>
</body>
</html>
```

but I strongly recommend you to not use `scriplets` in your JSP, have a look at [How to avoid Java Code in JSP-Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3180202/1551233)

Answer (score 1):

The `null` value returned by the `request.getParameter("command")` is due to the fact that you are using `enctype="plain/text"` in your jsp.

The default encoding for an HTTP post request (what your servlet is expecting) is application/x-www-form-urlencoded; not text/plain.

Comment: @divyabharathi OP has not mentioned anywhere that he is using `enctype="multipart/form-data`, OP is using `enctype=text/plain`

Comment: @Bhushan May be her intention is to use that one,instead of text/plain

Comment: @Baadshah using `multipart/form-data` will not solve the problem, but surely it will complicate it more, because looking at the code there is no need to use `multipart/form-data`

Comment: @Baadshah yes I know that, I was just pointing it, now this answer will work